# Is there any way to count search query results?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to create test for ticket sale website and I need to count results which are returned after search query, I tried with results.children().its('length'), but it returns not correct count. is there are any good way to display results?

my code

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})

    context('Actions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.tiketa.lt/EN/search')
  })

  //

  it('autotestsdd', () => {
  // selects caption and enters "corteo"
    cy.get('.btn-toolbar > .twitter-typeahead > .tt-input')
      .type('Corteo{esc}')
      .should('have.value', 'Corteo')   
    cy.get('#dropdownMenu4').click()
    cy.get('#search-location > .col-sm-8 > .btn-toolbar > .row > div.col-xs-12 > .btn-group > .dropdown-menu > :nth-child(17) > a')
      .click()
    cy.get('.search-time > .col-sm-8 > .row > :nth-child(1)')
      .find('[type="text"]')
      .type('2022-01-01')
      .should('have.value', '2022-01-01') 
    cy.get('.col-sm-8 > .row > :nth-child(2)')
      .find('[type="text"]')
      .type('2022-03-31')
      .should('have.value', '2022-03-31') 
    cy.get('.search-time > .col-sm-4 > .search-block-label')
    .click()
    cy.get('.bn')
     .should('is.enabled')
     .should('contain','Search') 
     .click()
    cy.get('.advanced-search > :nth-child(1)')
      .should('contain','CIRQUE DU SOLEIL - CORTEO')
    cy.get('#btnBuy-22551') 
      .should('be.enabled')
      .should('contain','Buy')
      .click()
      cy.get('.page-content col-xs-12').children().its('length')
    });
```

Comment: What are you validating? In the code provided, you're just getting the children length, but not doing anything with that value. Look at the example documentation for `.children()` and see if implementing the validation that way solves your issue: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children#Command-Log. If not, I'd recommend adding information about the specific error you're receiving and the DOM displayed at the time of failure.

Comment: I just need to log that value to be visible in test runner, I did not find proper way to do that

Comment: Cypress commands do not return subjects, but yield their subjects. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Subject-Management. I would look into the difference between returning vs. yielding. If you want to return the value of the list, you could look into aliasing: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to try the snippet below.  `cy.get('.page-content col-xs-12')` will find an array of elements.  You can use the `then` clause to resolve these elements and then just grab the number of elements using the `.length`

```js
cy.get('.page-content col-xs-12').then(elements => {
  cy.log('Number of search results found', elements.length);
})
```

I would also suggest using an assertion to test the number of results found against an expected number. For example:

```
cy.get('.page-content col-xs-12').should('have.length', numExpectedResults);
```